# Android 6.0: SD Card Directory creation fails in spite of having permissions

Tags: android, android-6.0-marshmallow

I am trying to create an external directory structure to move some files from Device storage to SD card in Android phones. I have followed the steps given in https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html and multiple stackoverflow answers. However, my program fails when I try to create the directories.

My `AndroidManifest.xml` file contains the following lines:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

The relevant code is as follows:

```
    public int mkFolder(String folderName){
        String state = Environment.getExternalStorageState();
        if (!Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED.equals(state)){
            Log.d(TAG, "Error: external storage is unavailable");
            return 0;
        }
        if (Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED_READ_ONLY.equals(state)) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Error: external storage is read only.");
            return 0;
        }
        Log.d(TAG, "External storage is not read only or unavailable");

        boolean writePermission = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED;
        boolean readPermission = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED;
        final boolean permissionNotGranted = writePermission|| readPermission;
        if (permissionNotGranted) {
            Log.i(TAG, "STORAGE permissions NOT granted");
            // Should we show an explanation?
            boolean shouldShowRationaleForWritePermssion = ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
            boolean shouldShowRationaleForReadPermssion = ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this, Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
            if (shouldShowRationaleForWritePermssion || shouldShowRationaleForReadPermssion) {

                // Show an explanation to the user *asynchronously* -- don't block
                // this thread waiting for the user's response! After the user
                // sees the explanation, try again to request the permission.

            } else {
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, PERMISSIONS_STORAGE, REQUEST_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
            }
        } else {
            Log.i(TAG, "STORAGE permissions granted");
        }

//        File folder = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DCIM),folderName);
        File folder = new File(folderName);
        int result = 0;
        if (folder.exists()) {
            Log.d(TAG,"folder exist:"+folder.toString());
            result = 2; // folder exist
        }else{
            try {
                if (folder.mkdirs()) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "folder created:" + folder.toString());
                    result = 0; // folder created
                } else {
                    Log.d(TAG, "create folder fails:" + folder.toString());
                    result = 1; // create folder fails
                }
            }catch (Exception ecp){
                ecp.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return result;
    }

    public static final int REQUEST_EXTERNAL_STORAGE = 112;
    private static String[] PERMISSIONS_STORAGE = {
            Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,
            Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
    };

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode,
                                           @NonNull String permissions[], @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        Log.e(TAG, "onRequestPermissionsResult invoked");
        switch (requestCode) {
            case REQUEST_EXTERNAL_STORAGE: {
                // If request is cancelled, the result arrays are empty.
                if (grantResults.length > 0
                        && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

                    // permission was granted, yay! Do the
                    // contacts-related task you need to do.
                    Log.i(TAG, "Permission to write to external storage granted");
                    Toast.makeText(this, "Permission to write to external storage granted", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                } else {
                    // permission denied, boo! Disable the
                    // functionality that depends on this permission.
                    Log.e(TAG, "Permission to write to external storage NOT granted");
                    Toast.makeText(this, "Permission to write to external storage NOT granted", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }
            // other 'case' lines to check for other
            // permissions this app might request
        }
    }
```

Here is an extract from the logs:

```
MainActivity: /storage/0000-0000    false   true
MainActivity: /storage/0000-0000/MyDir does not exist. Creating target parent directory
MainActivity: STORAGE permissions granted
MainActivity: Creation of directory /storage/0000-0000/MyDir failed with return value 1. Aborting...
```

Can someone please help me understand what the mistake is in my code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not have direct filesystem access to arbitrary locations on [removable storage](https://commonsware.com/blog/2014/04/09/storage-situation-removable-storage.html), starting with Android 4.4. `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` is meaningless here, as [external storage](https://commonsware.com/blog/2014/04/08/storage-situation-external-storage.html) is not removable storage.

Use the Storage Access Framework (`ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE` and kin) instead. Or, limit your work to the removable storage locations returned as part of `getExternalFilesDirs()`, `getExternalCacheDirs()`, and `getExternalMediaDirs()` (all methods on `Context`).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Does it mean that I cannot create directories at the root of the SD card? I have seen some other apps (like SMS backup and restore kind of apps) that create directories in the 'root' of SD Card. Do you know of any other way in which to do that?

Comment: @KarthickS: Via the Storage Access Framework, the *user* can choose a place for you to create document trees (directories). That might be the root of some removable storage volume. It might be in some subdirectory of a removable storage volume. It might be using some other storage provider entirely (e.g., Google Drive). The beauty of the Storage Access Framework is that your app does not have to care. It just uses the `Uri` that you get back, along with support classes like `DocumentFile`, and you place the content where the user requested that you place it.

Comment: Thanks a lot. That is exactly what I wanted. As a relative newbie to Android Programming, I did not realize that Storage Access Framework existed at all.